# PNG transparency in CSS

Tags: css

I need to add transparency to the PNG that I'm using as background. How can I add transparency?

```
section#testimonials {
    height:  647px;
    background: url("../img/yellow_testimonial.png") repeat-x 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #e4e5e2;
    z-index: 500;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: You could change the `opacity` of the element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; actual PNG alpha transparency has nothing to do with CSS – your PNG image either contains alpha transparent pixels, or it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, if you has been saved correctly the .png file you should not have that problem. I see that in your css style don't have a background color defined.

Try this:

```
section#testimonials {
    height:  647px;
    background: url("../img/yellow_testimonial.png") repeat-x 0 0 #0099FF;
    padding: 0;
    color: #e4e5e2;
    z-index: 500;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

This is one option, another way that you can try is applying an **rgba** code, like this: `rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5)` on parent div background style.

I hope you find it helpful.